# Power query group by 4 columns but keep the rest

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have done a group by in Power query based on 4 columns and have applied "count rows" to it. The problem is that this then removes the remaining columns which I do need. I have tried highlighting all of the columns and then doing the group by but then the count column is not accurate.

So how can i keep the rest of the columns? Below is some sample data from the group by on the 4 columns.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**In group by menu, [add aggregation] choose Operation [All Rows]**

[image]

**then expand that new column into rows using the arrows on top**

[image]