# Power Bi Groupby rows to find max while keeping other columns

Tags: powerbi

I have spent a while trying to find a solution and managed to hack something together but it feels inefficient.

**Problem Statement**: I have 3 columns = ['Tool Name', 'Price', 'Country']
We group by Tool Name and max over the price. But we want to keep the country column, where for each tool name row with its corresponding max price, there will be the respective value of country  which is from the same row as the max price.

**Failed Method 1**:
Groupby and select all row, followed by expanding. Following from [Power query group by 4 columns but keep the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176079/power-query-group-by-4-columns-but-keep-the-rest)

However, after expanding, it adds row which defeats the purpose of performing the groupby.

**Current Solution**:
After groupby Tool Name only, I duplicated the original table and merge back the original table on tool name and price to get the correct country back into the groupby table. I then added this M code to take the first row of each match (since if I just expand, we will get back the same problem as above where rows are added)

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each Table.First([merged]))
```

Lastly, I remove the merged column.

But this requires so many additional steps as compared to other software such as JMP which has keep columns option or python pandas which we can keep other columns easily. Is there a better method in power bi?

Comment: Please can  you add sample data in markdown format as well as expected results.

Answer (score 0):

After your Group By on `Tool Name` with select all rows, eg:

```
Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Tool Name"}, {{"Rows", each _ }})
```

Add a Custom Column with like:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "TopCountry", each Table.Last(Table.Sort([Rows], "Price")))
```

Then expand that column:

```
= Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Country", {"Price", "Country"}, {"Price", "Country"})
```

And finally, drop the previous "Rows" column from the Group By.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the reply and example. Yes what we need is something similar but we want to group by Tool Name only and Max over the Price. So the result will be